# Minimal polynomial of $\zeta_p+\frac{1}{\zeta_p}+\zeta_q+\frac{1}{\zeta_q }$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory

We can calculate the minimal polynomial of $ 2\cos(\frac{2\pi}{7})=\zeta_7+\frac{1}{\zeta_7}$ over $\mathbb Q$ as $x^3+x^2-2x-1$ and simlary for $2\cos(\frac{2\pi}{5})=\zeta_5+\frac{1}{\zeta_5 }$.

Now my question is :

> Is there any way to calculate the  minimal polynomial of $\zeta_7+\frac{1}{\zeta_7}+\zeta_5+\frac{1}{\zeta_5 }$?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key is to use [resultants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant). If $P$ is the minimal polynomial of $x$, and $Q$ is the minimal polynomial of $y$, then the resultant of $P(x)$ and $Q(z-x)$ as a polynomial in $z$ vanishes when $z=x+y$. Factoring gives you the minimal polynomial of $x+y$.